# Need help restructuring loop/getting simple average code to work.

Tags: c, loops, average

First time working with C and I was asked to do a simple average function WITHOUT scanf (only using getchar) for my Systems class. I ended up writing an unnecessarily complicated loop just to get my code to compile and even after compiling+running it doesn't seem to do anything after taking in the keyboard input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//average program

//use getchar to get numbers separately instead of scanf and integers.
//Not sure why. Most likely to build character.

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char x,z;
    float avg;
    int tot,n,b;

    printf("Input Integer values from 1 to 100. Separate each value by a space. For example: 23 100 99 1 76\n");

     ret:

    x=getchar();
    while( x != '\n' );
    {
        if(x==isspace(x))
        { goto ret;}


     opd:

    z=getchar();
        if ((z == isspace(z)))
        {
            b = x - '0';//subtracting 0 from any char digit returns integer value
            tot +=b;
            n++;
            goto ret;
        }

        else if(z == '\n')
        {
            b = x - '0';
            tot +=b;
            n++;
            goto end;
        }

        else
        {
            x = x*10;
            x = x + z;
            goto opd;
        }
    }

    end:
    avg=tot/n;

    printf("Taking of the average of the values. The average is %1.2f\n",avg);

    return avg;

}
```

Comment: Are you not permitted to define your own functions?

Comment: Sorry, but that code is far below average. goto? And if you want more help, indent your submissions properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The semicolon in `while(...);` causes an infinite loop, it's the same as saying: `while(...) continue;`
2. You should use only one loop, and you should try to use only one call to `getchar()` ... it's too confusing with multiple `getchar()` calls and your code is trying to throw away the first line the way it's written.
3. Definitely get rid of the `goto` statement, your instructor won't like them and they are quite unnecessary. (Do read up on *break* and *continue*.)
4. In C parsers calling `getchar()` directly, it's useful to be able push a character back on the input stream. See `man 3 ungetc` or just write a simple wrapper around `getchar().` You should only need one character of pushback at the end of a parser loop.

Comment: Appreciate the tip on the ; after while.It definitely wasn't intentional and I hadn't caught it while looking over things.

I see what you're saying by the fact that my code is trying to throw away the first line. After i compiled the code again and gave it input, it return an average of 0.00.